# Is Possible to use both SDL blitting with Opengl in one window/application ( SDL_ANYFORMAT )

Tags: opengl, sdl

if this is possible, how would i go about doing it, can share a link or a code snipit

I've tried using SDL_ANYFORMAT and using this

```
RenderSurface ( 0, 0, pTexture, pMainSurface );

glColor3f ( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f );

glBegin( GL_QUADS );
     glVertex2f( -0.5f, -0.5f );
     glVertex2f(  0.5f, -0.5f );
     glVertex2f(  0.5f,  0.5f );
     glVertex2f( -0.5f,  0.5f );
glEnd();

SDL_Flip ( pMainSurface );
```

RenderSurface is a function i made which is this

```
void RenderSurface ( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* src, SDL_Surface* dst )
{
SDL_Rect offset;

offset.x = x;
offset.y = y;

SDL_BlitSurface ( src, NULL, dst, &offset );
}
```

this code only shows the Surface and not the quads from OpenGL

the only reason I want to that is because i'm currently more comfortable with the blitting system than I am with the Opengl Texture Mapping system

so again any kind of papar or tutorial would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

With SDL you can either let SDL Handle it for you (using SDL's blitting) or do it yourself with OpenGL.

I would recommend sticking with SDL if you are having trouble with OpenGL. Unless your ultimate goal is to make a 3D program. In which case I would recommend http://lazyfoo.net/ for tutorials on OpenGL. It start with the deprecated functionality (For learning not for using) and works its way up to programmable pipelines.

In SDL2 you can tell it to use HW acceleration (under the hood it's then basically OpenGL) : https://gist.github.com/armornick/3434362 (A simple HOWTO)

I think that's more or less what your wanted.